# Vagrant/Otto Malformed version: 1.7.4/lib/vagrant/pre-rubygems.rb:31

Tags: vagrant

This errors happened to me on Mac environment when using the command `otto dev` from [Otto](https://hashicorp.com/blog/otto.html) (successor of vagrant, nothing to do what android), but I think this error my happen to some people using only vagrant.

The error:

`$ otto dev
Error building dev environment: Malformed version: 1.7.4/lib/vagrant/pre-rubygems.rb:31`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but Otto or Ruby may not show the complete error message, the complete error message is a warning that I found using the command bellow:

`$vagrant --version
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/pre-rubygems.rb:31: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Vagrant 1.7.4`

Attention on this part about the dir: writable dir **/usr/local/bin**

**Solution**

To fix, I use: `sudo chmod go-w /usr/local/bin`

But, then again, with me at least, more similar errors appeared, the difference was the dir changed, was `/usr/local`, then `/usr/local/bit/bin`, then finally `/usr/local/git` I have used the chmod above on all those dirs and now `otto dev` works!

Comment: Then use ```sudo chmod go-w /usr/local```